# .NET DropDownList SelectedIndexChange Event Not Firing in IE 10

Tags: .net, postback, internet-explorer-10

In IE 10, when a drop down list selected item is changed, nothing happens. It doesn't post back. All other controls work except for drop down lists.

It appears to work when I switch to IE 10 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a weird issue. The actual problem was that ***we had a web.config sitting in the very root of the application*** that had OLD, I'm talking ANCIENT browserCap definitions in there. I'm talking browserCap definitions for Windows TV kind of old.

We removed the browserCap definitions in this file, and all was fine.

If you run into this error, please check for any browser caps that are not in the immediate folder of your project (if you have that sort of setup).

The link in Michael's answer will most likely take care of you if you're experiencing this problem and do not have multiple web.config's in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman explains this on his blog.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Comment: In addition to a link, please copy some text giving a quick explanation and add that to your answer as well. Links eventually die.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [ASP.net Hotfix for IE10](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) installed?

Comment: Yes. Installed and still not working properly. Javascript is not disabled and other calls to __doPostBack seem to be working fine as all click events seem to work.

Comment: Have you set AutoPostBack="True" on the drop down list?

Comment: Yes. All of them have AutoPostBack set to "true".

Comment: Not too sure I can do that. The source doesn't belong to me, belongs to the company I work for.

It seems to only happen in IE10 and it seems to only be in IE 10 browser mode. In all other browsers and in all other "browser modes" it works.

Comment: I'm not setting the handlers via aspx, but instead am using the codebehind to handle the SelectedIndexChange events on all asp:DropDownLists.

Comment: Michael, I think you are on to something after looking at it more carefully. I don't see __doPostBack in the source and it's not available via the console either.