# asp.net Dropdownlist onselectedIndexChanged does not fire in IE 10

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I have simple (no ajax, no update panels) Asp.net application with a form which contains a server side DropdownList control. It works fine in all browsers except IE 10. DropdownList does not fire OnSelectedIndexChanged event. If I enable Compatibility view in IE 10 again it works. But I'm not able to get it working for normal mode in IE 10.

I read - [.NET DropDownList SelectedIndexChange Event Not Firing in IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615446/net-dropdownlist-selectedindexchange-event-not-firing-in-ie-10) and subsequent links in the answers. But nothing has helped yet. Anybody else has encountered this issue before?

Comment: I have one and it works fine, what are you firing? and how does it act in lower versions?

Comment: can you put your code?

Comment: Can you post your code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it wont work... it is IE10 draw-back.

To make it work properly, you need to make you application IE10 compatible by adding a file "ie.browser" in App_Browser folder...
[Check this out](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

Comment: As I said in the question itself, I did got to this link with the link I mentioned in my question. I installed the hotfix what Scott suggested but that did not work. Now I took those raw files and replaced my self and can see it working now. thanks!

Comment: For me in IE11 following solution works
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20422240/2089963
it also similar to HotFix u provided

Answer (score 0):

The issue is ASP.NET browser definitions do not recognize IE10 so it defaults to a down-level definition, which has certain inconveniences, like that it does not support features like JavaScript.

An alternative to the machine wide hotfix(s) or site level App_Browser solutions is to simply add Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel" to the Page_Init method in the code behind.

Example:

```
private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel";     
}
```