# Submit button stops working after postback in IE11

Tags: asp.net, webforms, internet-explorer-11

**Problem:**

> Sometimes submit button stops working after postback in IE11. It's
>   clickable, but it doesn't trigger any event. There is no script or
>   server side errors. Even the right click menu doesn't show on button.
>   If clicked somewhere on page it starts to work normally.

Button is general ASP.NET button

Server side:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" SkinID="Button82" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Client side:

```
<input name="ctl00$cphMain$Substitution$btnSave" class="button82" id="cphMain_Substitution_btnSave" type="submit" value="Save">
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you using .NET framework 4.0?

Comment: see if this helps [asp.net Dropdownlist onselectedIndexChanged does not fire in IE 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914538/asp-net-dropdownlist-onselectedindexchanged-does-not-fire-in-ie-10)

Comment: Yes, and even switched to 4.5, still no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

For now I solved it using this in postback:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Refocus", "RefocusIE11()", true);
```

It calls function after postback, that refocuses on next element. This makes button to work again.