# DropDownlist Selected Index changed not working in IE10

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-10

In IE 10, when a drop down list selected item is changed, nothing happens i.e `SelectedIndexChanged` is not being fired. It works when I change to IE 10 Compatability View. Please suggest if anyone faced this issue. Thanks

I have followed http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx 
and added a App_Browser folder to my project. Manually added the .browser files. But still it is not working. Anything else is required to be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615446/net-dropdownlist-selectedindexchange-event-not-firing-in-ie-10

Comment: Yes it is almost same. But i don't understand the work around he is telling to resolve this. If anyone having any solution please elaborate it.

Comment: I'm using IE 10.0.9200.16635 on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012. DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged fires correctly. What is the IE and VS version are you using?

Comment: IE 10 and Visual Studio 2008 is being used. It is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I manually added the ie.browser file in "http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx" to the App_Browser folder of the web application.